# Kaufmann's experiment 1902

Tags: mass, electrons, charge

Kaufmann's experiments (1902):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaufmann%E2%80%93Bucherer%E2%80%93Neumann_experiments#Historical_context

About charge to electromagnetic-mass ratio.

Fig 2 has a plot of e/m versus v/c for 4 data points. 
v/c : 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95; 
e/m: 1.17 to 0.75.

Can someone clarify how the velocity of the electrons was measured.

Answer (score 1):

I have annotated the diagram in the Wikipedia article that you cited in your question.
Note that the signs for the charges on the parallel plates were the wrong way round in the article.

[image]

To simplify the derivation I assume that the condenser plate length is approximately the same as the source to aperture distance ($AS = a)$ and the angular deflections due to the electric field are small.

Where I have used commonly used symbols I have not defined them.

Dealing with the deflection due to the electric field $E$ in the y-direction first.

The electron takes a time $\Delta t = \dfrac a v$ to get from the source to the aperture.

In that time the y-component of the electron velocity $u$ which is assumed to be small compared with the x-component $v$ has its direction reversed and so equating impulse to change in momentum gives $eE \Delta t = 2mu$

This gives $\dfrac {eEa}{2mv^2}= \dfrac u v \approx \dfrac y b$ as the trajectories of the electrons outside the electric field are straight lines.

So $\dfrac{e}{mv^2} = \dfrac {2y}{Eab}$ with everything on the right hand side being measured during the experiment.

For the magnetic field deflection using Newton's second law $Bev = m\dfrac {v^2}{r}$ which gives $\dfrac{e}{mv} = \dfrac {1}{Br}$

Now $r$ can be found using geometry given the fact that the electron passes through three points $(0,0,0), \; (0,0,a)$ and $(a+b,0,z)$ and the general equation of a circle in the x-z plane is $(x-k)^2 + (z-m)^2 = r^2 \Rightarrow r^2 = \dfrac {a^2}{4}+ \left ( \dfrac{b^2 + ab +z^2}{2z}\right)$.

So you now have values for $\dfrac{e}{mv}$ and $\dfrac{e}{mv^2}$ for a series of values of $y$ and $z$ from which you can find $v$ and the corresponding value of $\dfrac e m$.